# Prolog: Why is member/2 not working properly here?

Tags: prolog

I encountered an interesting problem:

In my code, `[R|Rs]` is the rest of a list generated by removing `Seq` from `SortedRanks`. It is going to have 1 or 2 elements. The number depends on the length of `Seq`, and `Length` can be 3 or 4.

If the length is 4, `[R|Rs]` would only have one element;

If the length is 3, `[R|Rs]` would have two elements.

However, when length is 3 and I try to use `member/2` to seek whether `Rs` (which I think is the last element in `[R|Rs]`) is in `Seq`, even though `Rs` is in it, `member/2/` returns false. I'm really confused here.

Following is my code:

```
calculate_run( SortedRanks, Seq, [R|Rs], Length, Seq ) :-
  remove_list(SortedRanks, Seq, [R|Rs]),
  ( Length = 4 ->
    ( member(R,Seq) -> Number is 2 ; Number is 1 )
  ;
    ( member(R,Seq) ->
      ( member(Rs,Seq) ->
        ( R =:= Rs ->
            Number is 3
          ;
            Number is 4
        )
      ;
        Number is 2
      )
    ;
      ( member(Rs,Seq) ->
        Number is 2
      ;
        Number is 1
      )
    )
  ),
  Points is Length * Number .
```

The main problem is `member(Rs,Seq)` not returning correct boolean values. I'm new to prolog and yeah I admit this isn't an elegant solution, but that's the best I can do right now.

Comment: I'm just going to note that this nested bunch of soft cuts is begging to be refactored into much simpler additional predicates and/or clauses.

Comment: Yeah I'd appreciate any simpler and more elegant solution than this...

Comment: The original problem has been solved. And another reason why I deleted my code is that this is going to be submitted and I don't want simularity checkers find my own code on the Internet and call me a plagiariser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't tell what you're doing without any examples, but I suspect "*even though Rs is in it*" is not accurate; I guess your problem is that in `[R|Rs]`, Rs is a list not an element.

> If the length is 4, [R|Rs] would only have one element

Unifying with a one element list: `[R|Rs] = [5]` and `R=5` and `Rs=[]`.

> If the length is 3, [R|Rs] would have two elements.

Unifying with a two element list: `[R|Rs]=[5,6]` and `R=5` and `Rs=[6]` not `Rs=6`.

e.g.

```
?- [R|Rs] = [1,2],
member(Rs, [1,2,3]).

false
```

because `[2]` is not a member of `[1,2,3]`.

```
?- [R|Rs]=[1,2],
member(Rs, [1,[2],3]).

R = 1,
Rs = [2]
```

because `[2]` is a member of `[1,[2],3]`.

Comment: @EmanueleFiliberto That's good; you could possibly do that more directly with `[R|[Rs]]` or `[R|Rs_], Rs_ = [Rs]`.